# How to organize architecture of an isomorphic app using docker?

Tags: nginx, dns, docker, isomorphic-javascript

I am developing an isomorphic app. The key moment here is that js code on frontend server and on client is the same.

Suppose we have the following services:

- frontend
- backend
- comments
- database

Of course each of these services lives in it's own docker container.

And there is a need to access `backend` and `comments` services from client side (as `api.app.com` and `comments.app.com` respectively).

It seems pretty reasonable to use `nginx` as reverse proxy here. So these are new containers to be added:

- nginx
- consul
- consul-template
- registrator

And the last problem is to resolve `*.app.com` to `nginx`. How to achieve this without buying `app.com` domain? Of course solution is to add DNS to each container and to dev host. But what docker container should I use as DNS server?

Or maybe there is better architecture?